# Error while compiliing CyanogenMod 13

Tags: android, android-source

i keep getting this error when it builds the kernel module. i tried to go to the directory to fix it. (built-in.o)  it didnt work and caused more problems with the build/kernel directory folder.

```
  LD      drivers/input/touchscreen/built-in.o
arm-eabi-ld: cannot find /home/taco/android/system/kernel/lge/msm8909/drivers/input/touchscreen/ft_gesture_lib.a: No such file or directory
/home/taco/android/system/kernel/lge/msm8909/scripts/Makefile.build:387: recipe for target 'drivers/input/touchscreen/built-in.o' failed
make[5]: *** [drivers/input/touchscreen/built-in.o] Error 1
/home/taco/android/system/kernel/lge/msm8909/scripts/Makefile.build:455: recipe for target 'drivers/input/touchscreen' failed
make[4]: *** [drivers/input/touchscreen] Error 2
/home/taco/android/system/kernel/lge/msm8909/scripts/Makefile.build:455: recipe for target 'drivers/input' failed
make[3]: *** [drivers/input] Error 2
/home/taco/android/system/kernel/lge/msm8909/Makefile:815: recipe for target 'drivers' failed
make[2]: *** [drivers] Error 2
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/taco/android/system/kernel/lge/msm8909'
build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:286: recipe for target 'TARGET_KERNEL_BINARIES' failed
make: *** [TARGET_KERNEL_BINARIES] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/home/taco/android/system'

#### make failed to build some targets (11:59 (mm:ss)) ####

taco@taco-VirtualBox:~/android/system$
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it happens when repo manifest uses projects of incompatible version, say if you take CM13 manifest and add msm8909 drivers which were built against some older kernel version than that used in CM13 manifest.

Are you building an existing official or unofficial CM port for your device, or do you assemble a new port? In any case you should provide more info about your repo manifest and CM port if you use any.

If the issue is that I described, it is usually hard to fix, as it means porting driver code to a newer kernel version. This work is usually made by people maintaining driver's code, it needs proper experience. Of course there's a chance that it may need just cosmetic changes, but it's a rare case.

In your repo manifest check what git repository is used for the driver, then check for what kernel version that code was used (it's usually can be seen in git tags/branches). There's a chance that the repo has an updated branch for kernel version you need, but your repo manifest takes an old version.